# Simplest Method to Conditionally Assign Variable With Fallbacks

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I frequently find myself checking more than 1 function to determine the proper value for a variable but I don't think I'm doing it the most efficient way.

Currently,

```
$var = false;
if($var = first_function_to_check()){
    do_this_thing($var);
} elseif($var = fallback_function_to_check()){
    do_this_thing($var);
}
```

If `first_function_to_check` returns a value, I'm all set, but if it comes back false, I want to check `fallback_functon_to_check`.  If that also comes back false, then the variable is still set to false.

I use something close to this fairly regularly but I know there has to be a better shorthand method so that I don't have multiple lines referencing `do_this_thing()` for the same purpose

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
$var = false;

if(first_function_to_check($var) || fallback_function_to_check($var)){
    do_this_thing($var);
}

function first_function_to_check(&$var)
{
    // some condition that means you return true
    if(some_condition){
        $var = 'abc'
    }

    return $var; // either true or false 
}

function fallback_function_to_check(&$var)
{
    // some other condition that means you return true
    if(some_other_condition){
        $var = 'xyz'
    }

    return $var; // either true or false
}
```

There are two significant points to note here:

1) The function signatures are defined as `(&$var)`, with the `&` symbol. This means that the value is passed as a reference, meaning that any alterations that the function makes to `$var` will be reflected outside of the function. So, where previously you were returning a value back to `$var`, that is no longer needed as you are passing the variable to the function, so it can reassign its value internally. **This means that by the time you pass `$var` to `do_this_thing()`, it's value is the value that your functions made it become**.

2) The code will only ever go into `fallback_function_to_check($var)` if `first_function_to_check($var)` returns false. So, following on from point 1, `$var` will only ever be affected by `fallback_function_to_check($var)` if `first_function_to_check($var)` returns false.

Of course, if both return false, `do_this_thing($var)` is never called, and `$var` remains false.